# In Delphi XE6 using cxTreeList does not allow to change column order

Tags: delphi

I am using cxTreeList and delphi XE6 after setting the "ColumnQuickCustomization" property to true I am able to see the columns in left side as shown in image below:
[image]
After that I try to change the order of Column "b" ,as shown in image below:
[image]
So after changing the order I can see it as original only in left side box **marked in red**.

Can anyone help me on what I need to set inorder to get the correct column order in left side box ?

Comment: `ColumnsQuickCustomizationSorted`, set it to false.

Comment: @BrakNicku Thanks for the suggesion. However  this property "ColumnsQuickCustomizationSorted" is not found in cxtreelist

Comment: Means that you are using some old version and did not include that information in the question.

Comment: @BrakNicku can you please tell which version of devexpress you are using?

Comment: @BrakNicku I am using Delphi XE6

Comment: @BrakNicku I checked online and it show that in this version of devexpress v18.1.1 they have introduced this property . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @BrakNicku Can you please confirm if you can see this property "ColumnsQuickCustomizationSorted" in TcxTreeList ?

Comment: Yes, I can see it - that is why I suggested using it... To be precise it is property of `OptionsCustomizing` property of the list, so same place where `ColumnQuickCustomization` is.

Comment: @BrakNicku ok sure.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please fix the question regarding versions. I doubt versions really matter here but if you mention them, get them right. Also XE does exist but I'm sure you aren't using it.